# Configuration lost in my server after rebooting

Tags: linux

I have done `apt-get update` in my server linux - debian and after rebooting the server it get lost all the configuration. I mean it is booting from different partition. Any idea of what happened?

Answer (score 0):

If your other partition is still there, it should be enough to mount it to any directory :

```
mount /dev/old_partition666 /any_dir
```

then you can try to find your missing etc. To avoid it in future use [etckeeper](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/etckeeper.html)